# Java ScrumTestExercices

Tags: java

I'm new into `Java` and if if someone can explain me what it's the logic of implementation of this code 
`getTotalOreRamaseSprint(Sprint sprint, Member member)` , `getTotalOreRamaseCerinta(Cerinta cerinta, Team team)` and `getTotalOreRamaseCerinta(Cerinta cerinta)`.

```
public Integer getTotalOreRamaseCerinta(Cerinta cerinta, Member member)
 {
         Integer totalOreRamaseCerinta= 0;
         for(Task t: cerinta.getTaskuri())
         {
                 if(t.getResponsable().equals(member))
                         totalOreRamaseCerinta += t.getTimpRamas();
         }
         return totalOreRamaseCerinta;
 }
```

---

```
 public Integer getTotalOreRamaseSprint(Sprint sprint, Member member)
 {
         return null;
 }
```

---

```
 public Integer getTotalOreRamaseCerinta(Cerinta cerinta, Team team)
 {
         return null;
 }
```

---

```
 public Integer getTotalOreRamaseCerinta(Cerinta cerinta)
 {
         return null;
 }
```

Comment: put it in a debugger and step through the logic

Comment: fulfilling an interface? I can't tell what the context is from what has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

welcome, I am not usually active in the community, but I was curious given the title of your questions.

I would suggest changing the name, as `ScrumTestExcercises` seems to refer either to any of the flavors of Scrum / Agile certification, but there, there are no Java nor code requirements.

I would avoid the [scrum](/questions/tagged/scrum) tag too.

Regarding your purely technical question [java](/questions/tagged/java), I can't get the background of the code in base to what is stated in that lines.

The three bottom methods, do nothing, basically each time you call them, independently of the parameters, they will return null.

In the only method with code, it is assuming that `Cerinta` has a member which is a `Collection` of `Task`.

The `for` loop iterates over each of the `Task` and if the `Task` contains a `member` that is the same as the `Member` received as a parameter, it will add the `Task` value `TimpRamas` to the counter.

After iterating each `Task` the result of the additions will be returned, which is accumulated in `totalOreRamaseCerinta`

Hope this helps, not really sure if this was the goal of your question.

Comment: I recommend not answering poor questions until the asker makes it clear what they're trying to ask. However, I do not agree with the people who **downvote** such contributions as as you have provided. Be warned that you may receive some, though.